# How to join two lists and exclude where property values don't match

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following class which I am using for conflicit resolution:

```
  public class DTOVariance
  {
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public object? OriginalValue { get; set; }
    public object? EditedValue { get; set; }
  }
```

Usage: compare versions of the same record and returns a list of variances:

```
var dbVariances = srOrig.GetVariances(srDb);
var editedVariances = srOrig.GetVariances(srEdited);
```

What I'm trying to do now is do a join between the two lists based on the PropertyName and also exclude sets where EditedValue don't equal each other.

So far what I have is:

```
var validVariances = (from dbv in dbVariances
                     join editedv in editedVariances
                     on dbv.PropertyName equals editedv.PropertyName
                     where dbv.EditedValue != editedv.EditedValue //*** Not working as expected
                     select new DTOVariance
                     {
                       PropertyName = dbv.PropertyName,
                       OriginalValue = dbv.OriginalValue,
                       EditedValue = editedv.EditedValue
                     }).ToList();
```

However the where clause is not excluding items where EditedValue is equal.
Must be missing something, how can I resolve this?

Comment: maybe you need ToLower ? you use !bv.EditedValue.Equals(editedv.EditedValue ) ?
Did you check the query going to the database?

Comment: you compare 2 objects....what are they...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to compare `2 types object`, so the simple equality is more complex than just test with `==`. Behind an object type, there are plenty of differents types derived....

Depend how is the value of each object, you could try to compare hashcode of each object or the best is to use a comparator or a custom method to compare your 2 objects

```
public bool CompareTwoObjects(object first, object second)
{  
        if(first == null && second != null) return false;
        if(first != null && second == null) return false; 
         
        //implement your test for the both object
}
```

Comment: He could use a record. This lets you do object == object.

Answer (score 1):

I think your linq may be a little overly complex. In your return, you are using the `PropertyName` and `OriginalValue` from `dbv`, and the `EditedValue` from `editedv`. But since you want to exclude any results where the `EditedValue` is different between `dbv` and `editedv` you can just use the `dbv` values for all three properties. As an example:

```
var results = dbVariances.Where(d => editedVariances.firstOrDefault(e => e.PropertyName 
== d.PropertyName && e.EditedValue == d.EditedValue) != null).ToArray();
```

This will only return the items where both a `PropertyName` exists in both lists and the `EditedValue` matches in both.

Keep in mind, this has a complexity of O(n^2). Not an issue for small data sets.